# aborted prematurely while running update #7204

Tags: updating

I get this message but nothing is logged (that I can see)

The update process was aborted prematurely while running update #7204 in wysiwyg.module. All errors have been logged. You may need to check the watchdog database table manually.

Answer (score 1):

I did more digging and found it is because the wysiwyg module was disabled. I enabled it and the update worked.